# Bluetooth LE on iOS sometimes slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth

I am developing a multiplayer game for iPads using bluetooth LE to transfer data. The iPads sends messages to an iPad serving as peripheral about 30 times per second.

I am developing in ionic, with a plugin for bluetoothle: 
https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle

The problem is that the latency of the write and notify operations varies a lot. Sometimes it can be as much as 2 seconds, while most of the time it is negligible. Is there anything in iOS that could cause this?

I somewhat understand the source code and I believe I can make smaller changes to it if needed.

I have tried inserting:

```
#define DEFAULT_DESIRED_MIN_CONN_INTERVAL     10
#define DEFAULT_DESIRED_MAX_CONN_INTERVAL     20
```

At the start of the m-file.

Thanks in advance,
Markus

Comment: What is the size of packets that you are sending? Is it 20 bytes? Are you sending 1 packet per 2 seconds?

Comment: It is less than 20 bytes. I trying to send about 30 packages per second. Most of the time it works but sometimes the latency is very high(up to 2 seconds). I am thinking maybe iOS limits the latency somehow, maybe to save battery..